# Application crash after detect null variable

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TreeView` where I want to get `NextNode` so I do simple like:

```
var nextNode = e.Node.NextNode.Text;
```

If it have nextNode it returns value right. Problem if it comes null, application crash and throw

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode.NextNode.get returned null.

Why application crash? should not return the null variable instead application crash?

Comment: You can't use the Text property if NextNode is null.  Check first.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that an instance of `NextNode` does not exist yet you attempt to access the `Text` property.

You have two options:

1. Retrieve the `NextNode` object and check for NULL
2. Use the null coalescing operator to access the text or substitute it.

## 1 - Check for null

```
NextNode node = e.Node.NextNode;
string thetext = string.Empty;
if (node != null)
    thetext = node.Text
```

## 2 - Null coalescing operator

```
string thetext = e.Node?.NextNode?.Text ?? string.Empty;
```

They will both do the same thing. If `NextNode` is null then the variable `thetext` will contain an empty string, otherwise it will contain the `Text` of `NextNode`.